# MongoClient.connect(....)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, hosts

подскажите, пожалуйста, как исправить ошибку

```
MongoClient.connect('mongodb://' + config.mongo.host + ':' + config.mongo.port + '/fastdelivery', function(err, db) {
                                               ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'host' of undefined
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\nir7\app\app.js:73:48)
    at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
    at Module.runMain (module.js:604:10)
    at run (bootstrap_node.js:389:7)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:149:9)
    at bootstrap_node.js:502:3
```

Answer (score 2):

У вас есть объект `config` (наверное), но в нём нет поля `mongo` и следовательно `config.mongo.host`, `config.mongo.port` тоже не заданы.

Answer (score 0):

```
'mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/fastdelivery'
```

лучше уж так